# How do I make journalctl messages show up in red?

Tags: systemd, journalctl

Some error messages in `journalctl` show up in red and white. If I'm authoring my own `systemd` service, how can I format my messages such that they show up in red or white. It's a nice way of having errors stand out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the priority that determines how journalctl displays messages.

Based on a quick test with `logger` :

- Messages of priority `debug` and `info` are displayed "normally".
- Messages of priority `notice` and `warning` are displayed in bold white.
- Messages of priority `err`, `crit`, `alert`, `emerg` are displayed in bold red.

Edit:

To answer the comment about how to indicate a level just by writing to stdout, yes you can, just prefix your message with `<n>` where n is a number between 0 (emerg) and 7 (debug) representing the priority.

For example the following service writes an `alert` message, which will thus appear in red in journalctl output :

```
[Unit]
Description=Loth

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/echo "<1>Victoriae mundis et mundis lacrima."

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

See `sd-daemon(3)` and http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/journal-submit.html for more details.

Comment: If your service is just writing to stdout, is there a way to indicate loglevel?